# Unable to access $scope model

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my main html, I have a view which loads templates.

```
<div data-ng-view></div>
```

It loads a html whenever the link is clicked.

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
'use strict';

$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "events.html"      
    }); 

}]);
```

On this page (template) , I have a directive which loads another html file

```
app.directive('ngPost', function () {
'use strict';

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'postbox.html'
};


});
```

I then use this directive on my events.html page by using `<div data-ng-Post></div>`

In postbox, I have two input fields and a button

```
<input type="text" id="user" data-ng-model="username" /> 
<input type="text" id="mess" data-ng-model="message"/>
<button data-ng-click="Add(eventid-1, username, message)">Post</button>
```

Upon clicking the button, I have some operations, then I try to clear the input fields, but I cannot. Method here :

```
 $scope.Add = function (index, uname, msg) {

    var a = {user: uname,   message: msg, time: new Date()};

    $scope.data[index].messages.push(a);

    $scope.message = ''; // clearing here
    $scope.username ='';


};
```

The clearing does not happen, I do not know why. My controller that has this Add method wraps the `<div data-ng-view></div>`in the main html file so it is the outermost controller and should have access to all $scope models inside. Why does it not work?
Note that the operations before the clearing works with no problems

Comment: Believe you should have an error in your console don't think it will be able to properly parse this eventid-1.  Can add a `debugger;` line in your Add function as well to see if it is triggered at all.  Last point good to not use the $scope as your model rather have it point to an object that is your model, google angular prototypical inheritance and see the SO post

Comment: @shaunhusain the debugger triggers. and there are no errors, my operations which i excluded uses the information from the inputs ( which has no problem)

Comment: If you console.log($scope.message) and console.log($scope.username) in your add method what's the output?

Comment: @MikeFeltman undefined, both

Comment: It's look like a scope mistmatch. directive have their own scope different from controller what happen if you set the rootScope ($rootScope) just to check if it's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your add method is in the parent scope. The parent's scope cannot see it's children, it works the other way around. The message and username properties are defined in the directive's child scope. From a child you can reference parent properties, but not the other way around.

If you add scope: false and transclude: false to your directive, it won't create it's own scope and instead use its parent's scope, so your directive would look something like this:

```
 angular.module('app', []).controller("myController",myController);

    function  myController($scope){
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.hello ="Hello"

    };

    angular.module('app').directive("childThing", function() {
        return {
            template: '<div>{{message}}</div><div>{{username}}</div>',
            scope: false,
            transclude: false,
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.username="Mike Feltman"
                $scope.message="Hi Mike"
            }
        }
    })
```

and you can access the elements that the directive adds to the scope from the parent like this:

```
    <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
        {{username}} in the parent.
        <div>{{ctrl.hello}}</div>
        <child-thing></child-thing>
    </div>
```

Update using your template:
    
        {{username}} in the parent.
        {{ctrl.hello}}

Javascript:

function  myController($scope){
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.hello ="Hello"

```
    $scope.add = function() {
        alert($scope.username)
    }

};

angular.module('app').directive("childThing", function() {
    return {
        template: '<input type="text" id="user" data-ng-model="username" /><input type="text" id="mess" data-ng-model="message"/>',
        scope: false,
        transclude: false,
    }
})
```

Comment: Updated to provide a way to do this.

Comment: @MikeFeltman is it necessary to define the controller in the directive? can I use the myController ( for instance your example) since my method is in myController?

Comment: The controller at the directive level is not necessary. The way you have defined the properties using ng-model will surface them on the parent.  I added that to the answer as well.

Comment: @MikeFeltman is there anything I need to change besides adding scope and translude to false in the directive? because the issue still persists after I added the two lines

Comment: Not that I know of. What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @MikeFeltman it should be 1.5, got it from the official website. I'm guessing it's the problem on my end. I'm using exactly the same code above , but adding the two lines. Anything else I'm missing? , nope there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113562/discussion-between-lessy-and-mike-feltman).